# main and sub encryption key on OpenPGP smartcard

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg, smartcard, key

The tutorial for creating and storing keys on an OpenPGP smartcard with GPG by the Free Software Foundation (FSF) at [wiki.fsfe.org](https://wiki.fsfe.org/TechDocs/CardHowtos/CardWithSubkeysUsingBackups?action=print#Remove_main_encryption_subkey) recommends creating a main and sub key for encryption, where the main key should not be stored on the card.

While the merit of a main key and sub keys (for authentication, signing and encryption) is amply documented, what's the merit of a main and sub key specifically for encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation is a bit weird. The reason why there is a "main encryption subkey" is, that the master key in that documentation is [created as a DSA key](https://wiki.fsfe.org/TechDocs/CardHowtos/CardWithSubkeysUsingBackups?action=print#Create_a_GnuPG_secret_key). And since DSA can only be used for signatures and not for encryption, gpg automatically creates a subkey for that purpose (for the ElGamal algorithm).

Since you are [creating two more subkeys](https://wiki.fsfe.org/TechDocs/CardHowtos/CardWithSubkeysUsingBackups?action=print#Generating_subkeys_for_the_card) lateron (of type RSA), that ElGamal key is not needed anymore and [thus deleted](https://wiki.fsfe.org/TechDocs/CardHowtos/CardWithSubkeysUsingBackups?action=print#Remove_main_encryption_subkey).

In the end you have one master key which you should only use to sign and revoke other keys and keep offline, and two subkeys for your daily use: One for signing, one for decrypting.